# SQL Date format BETWEEN query

Tags: c#, sql, datepicker, reportviewer

I have a table customer having some fields including date, now i want to print a report between 2 dates, but the format of date is like

```
Tuesday, October 02, 2012
```

i am using C# for query generation and send it to report viewer, suggest the query for this output.

C# Date Format is

```
string date = datetime.now.tostring("D");
```

Comment: What queries have you tried already?

Comment: The character `?` does not seem to occur in your post anywhere..

Comment: Is the date stored in the customer table as a string in the format shown or is it stored in a field with a Date type?

Answer (score 1):

I realize you said just SQL, but it doesn't seem like you're getting much help, so I'm going to show you how I would go about this using MySQL and hopefully it will help:

In C#, create the query string like this:

```
string date1 = dt1.ToString("D");
string date2 = dt2.ToString("D");
string query = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cast(entered_date_time as date) > STR_TO_DATE('" + date1 + "', '%W, %M %d, %Y') AND cast(entered_date_time as date) < STR_TO_DATE('" + date2 + "', '%W, %M %d, %Y');";
```

To give you a better view of the query, here's a sample what I'm doing:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE
cast(entered_date_time as date) > STR_TO_DATE('Monday, October 01, 2012', '%W, %M %d, %Y')
AND
cast(entered_date_time as date) < STR_TO_DATE('Tuesday, October 02, 2012', '%W, %M %d, %Y')
```

Also notice I used the field `entered_date_time` since date is a reserved keyword in MySQL.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, dates are stored in database as varchar, @Dan Maguire STR_TO_Date function not working in C#, it shows error to me.

Comment: @MoxetKhan - It's not a C# function, and I didn't tell you to call it in C#.  Let's start over so we can get the whole picture: How do you plan on calling this query?  Please show us code for what you've already tried.

Comment: My problem solved with between query, i took 2 dt pickers and run the query. dear i don't know why my reputation down day be day.